# Adicionar virgula a cada palavra

Tags: php

Ex.:

```
$str = "texto de teste";
// RESULTADO ESPERADO
$keywords = "texto, de, teste";
```

Comment: Se `$descricao` é um string não é mais fácil trocar os espaços em branco por virgulas?

Comment: Realmente não pensei nisso.. parece que estou complicando a situação, removendo os espaços e adicionando uma virgula.. pode dizer-me como posso fazer isso? creio que deva ser com str_replace, mas não tenho noção na prática..

Comment: Isso mesmo, com  `str_replace()`, veja se isso resolve o seu problema, tem outras abordagem. Você pode verificar as funções do php na documentação, veja a do str_replace, => http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php . É normal não lembrar a ordem dos argumentos de algumas funções ;)

Comment: Obrigado, consegui fazer com a ajuda do site 'php.net' e também a de Vaati.
De qualquer forma, deu certo.
Só não irei dar sua resposta como correta porque ele deixou bem claro, e se futuramente alguém tiver a dúvida, verá a resposta logo abaixo!

Comment: Eu sugiro, trabalhar com `array('word 1','word 2','word 3')` nesse caso, aí seria só dar um `$string_virgulas = implode(',', $dados_array)`.

Comment: Essa solução não seria nada prática Ivan, melhor usar funções de manipulação de string ao invés de criar arrays, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
str_replace(" ", ", ", $descricao);
```

Sempre que encontro um espaço ( ' ' ), substituo por vírgula mais espaço ( ', ' )

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda!
Olha só como eu estava tentando:
str_replace($descricao.' ' , $descricao.',' , $descricao);
Só deve ser dito aonde irá ser alterado no ultimo parametro, não é?! rs

Comment: Haha acontece amigo. De início é sempre assim. Mas, já que você está iniciando com PHP, qualquer dúvida sobre ele, veja nesse site aqui (já coloquei ele no tópico que fala sobre esse método 'str_replace': 
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-replace.php

Answer (score 3):

Eu faria um pouco diferente, usaria regex para remover os espaços adicionais.

```php
<?php
$exemplo = "texto de teste     com muitos   espaços talvez   erros de digitação";
$tags = preg_replace('/\s+/', ', ', $exemplo);
echo $tags . PHP_EOL;

$tags_2 = str_replace(" ", ", ", $exemplo);
echo $tags_2 . PHP_EOL;
```

Saídas:

**Saída preg_replace** `texto, de, teste, com, muitos, espaços, talvez, erros, de, digitação`

**Saída do código do str_replace** `texto, de, teste, , , , , com, muitos, , , espaços, talvez, , , erros, de, digitação`

Percebe a diferença? Espero que tenha o ajudado.

PS.: esta não é a "maneira correta", é só uma maneira alternativa, para quando existem espaços em demasia.

Answer (score -2):

Baseado no seu exemplo, bastaria fazer isso:

```
$descricao = 'titulo de teste';  
//aqui ele limpa espaços duplos, e substitui por um espaço
$descricao = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ',$descricao);  
$keywords = explode(' ',$descricao);
$listaComVirgula = implode(', ', $keywords);
echo $listaComVirgula;
```

Comment: Convenhamos .... funciona mas fica feio demais né

Comment: A resposta apresentada não é para ter beleza, é para elucidar a questão. Feiura é uma questão de ponto de vista.

Comment: Ivan não querendo ser ofensivo ... você já leu algo sobre KISS ? não estou dizendo que sua maneira esta errada, porém por que utilizar 5 linha se podemos fazer em 1 ? é questão de lógica.

Comment: @Otto, "kiss  - keep it simple stupid principle" já li sobre isso sim, eu sei onde há problema, e sei que poderia resolver fazendo isso: `$descricao = preg_replace('/\s+/', ', ',$descricao);`, mas o caso é abstrato, eu quis me basear na pergunta. Entendeu. Para toda pergunta há "n" respostas que eu poderia dar, no caso, é mais para mostrar na prática o uso do `implode()`. Não me pareceu ofensivo, mas pretensioso.

Comment: Galera, independente da maneira utilizada para responder a questão, vale ressaltar a vontade de vocês de ajudar, e fico feliz em saber que para caso há N soluções possíveis. Sou iniciante em PHP e tenho aprendido bastante aqui no stackoverflow.
De qualquer forma, obrigado!